# Compute $I(t) = \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^{k/2} \Gamma(\frac{k}{2})} x^{\frac{k}{2}-1}e^{-\frac{x}{2}} e^{jxt} dx$

Tags: integration, probability-distributions, improper-integrals, fourier-transform, characteristic-functions

I want to solve the following integral:

$$ I(t) = \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^{k/2} \Gamma(\frac{k}{2})} x^{\frac{k}{2}-1}e^{-\frac{x}{2}} e^{jxt} dx  $$

Where $j = \sqrt{-1}$, and $k \in \mathbb{N}$ and even.

I know that the answer is:

$$ I(t) = (1-j2t)^{-\frac{k}{2}}$$

---

So far, I let:

$$ u = \frac{x}{2} \Rightarrow x=2u, dx=2du $$

Thus we have:

$$ I(t) = \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^{k/2} \Gamma(\frac{k}{2})} (2u)^{\frac{k}{2}-1}e^{-u} e^{j2ut} 2du  $$
$$ I(t) = \frac{1}{\Gamma(\frac{k}{2})} \int_{0}^{\infty} 2^{-k/2}  2^{k/2}u^{\frac{k}{2}-1}e^{ju(2t+j)} du  $$
$$ I(t) = \frac{1}{\Gamma(\frac{k}{2})} \int_{0}^{\infty} u^{\frac{k}{2}-1}e^{ju(2t+j)} du  $$

Now I let:

$$ a = \frac{k}{2}-1 \quad b = 1-2t$$

This gives us:

$$ I(t) = \frac{1}{\Gamma(a+1)} \int_{0}^{\infty} u^{a}e^{-jbu} du  $$

Now I evaluated this via integration by parts. Letting:

$$ f(u) = u^{a} \quad g(u) = e^{-jbu} $$

We have

$$ I(t) = \frac{1}{\Gamma(a+1)} \Big(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^{n} (f^{(n)} \cdot g^{[n+1]})(u)\Big) \Big|_{0}^{\infty}$$

Where $f^{(n)}$ is the $n$-th derivative of $f$ and $g^{[n+1]}$ is the ($n+1$)-st antiderivative of $g$. This evaluates to:

$$ I(t) = \Big(\sum_{n=0}^{a} (-1)^{n} \frac{u^{a-n}}{(a-n)!} (-jb)^{-(a+1)} e^{-jbu} \Big)\Big|_{0}^{\infty}$$

---

However this is where I am stuck. I am having trouble taking the limits -- I just get infinity and zero.

What should I do next? Is this even the right approach? Any other ideas?

Comment: What you are trying to evaluate is the characteristic function of the Gamma distribution. Let $F(z)=\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^{k/2} \Gamma(\frac{k}{2})} x^{\frac{k}{2}-1}e^{-\frac{x}{2}} e^{zx} dx$ for $\Re (z)<\frac{1}{2}$. Then, $F$ is an analytic function with $F(r)=(1-2r)^{-\frac{k}2}$ for all real $r<\frac 12$. By analytic continuation, we can conclude $F(z)=(1-2z)^{-\frac k 2}$ and $F(jt)=(1-2jt)^{-\frac k 2}$ for all real $t$.

Comment: @Song By analytic continuation? Can you elaborate? Why should $Re(z) < \frac{1}{2}$ ? Where did you get that expression for F(r)? Sorry for the basic questions. I am only trying to learn how to evaluate these integrals.

Comment: Are you allowed to use Laplace transform? The integral is $\dfrac{\mathcal L\{x^{k/2-1};1/2-jt\}}{2^{k/2}\Gamma(k/2)}$ which is easily calculated using $\mathcal L\{x^\alpha;p\}=\dfrac{\Gamma(\alpha+1)}{p^{\alpha+1}}$ for all real $\alpha\gt -1$

Comment: @learner I am allowed to use anything I want. I just want to figure out how to get from A to Z here and improve my integration skills. Where did you get that last Laplace expression $L \{{x^{\alpha}, p}\}$? And...what does it expression actually mean exactly?

Comment: It is a standard result in introductory courses on Laplace transforms (just use the definitions): $$\mathcal L\{x^\alpha;p\}=\int_0^\infty x^\alpha e^{-px}~\mathcal dx\overset{t:=px}{=}\frac 1{p^{\alpha+1}}\int_0^\infty t^\alpha e^{-t}~\mathrm dt=\frac{\Gamma(\alpha+1)}{p^{\alpha+1}}$$

Comment: @learner. Thanks! I am starting from square one here, so that was very useful.

Comment: I am still hoping @Song replies and can elaborate. Their approach seems useful for other similar integrals as well...

Comment: @Song Interesting. Okay, I am going to have to look into this connection as well. Your last comment is a bit above my head right now too haha. Even then, I am not sure the moment generating function is easier to calculate!

Comment: @TheDude In a more probabilistic term, we can always find the characteristic function from the moment-generating function if the mgf exists. A basic idea here is that $F(z)$ is determined by its values on the real line by the analyticity, thus the information of $F(r)$ for $r$ real can be used to find $F(jt)$. Of course, in this case, mgf on the real line is much easier to calculate by using substitution and the definition of Gamma function.

Comment: Note that learner's substitution $t=px$ also changes the domain of the integral from the real line when $p$ has an imaginary part, so we need to justify that we can deform the contour back to the positive real line. (It's quite hard to type and edit a long comment in mobile... Anyway, I hope this will help somehow..)

Comment: @Song. It does. Okay so I understand how analyticity allows you to make the switch from $F(r)$ to $F(jt)$. This is analytic continuation, right? Ie Since $F(z)$ is analytic, we can evaluate it on the real line, and its solution will 'extend' or be continued to the plane. However, where did you get your expression for $F(r)$ where $r$ is real? And why must it be that $r<1/2$ ?